# How to stop the animation on a determinate NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: cocoa, animation, nsprogressindicator

NSProgressIndicator allows `stopAnimation:` when `isIndeterminate == YES`, but how does one stop the animation for determinate progress bars?

For context, the progress bar I am trying to do this with is a child of an NSView, which itself is the `view` property of an NSMenuItem.  Sending ridiculously high numbers to `setAnimationDelay:` does what I want, but only temporarily -- when the parent menu is closed and re-opened, the progress bar is animated again.

(Possibly unnecessary disclaimer: I swear this is a legit use case; I have to be able to *visually* (i.e.: without using text) display the progress of very-long-running tasks which may pause and re-start as needed by the backend.  Answers which boil down to "UI design: ur doin it rong" will be not be accepted unless accompanied by a brilliant alternative suggestion. ;) )

Comment: Is your progress indicator also showing changes in its value apart from animating? [Mine is doing neither...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833929/nsprogressindicator-in-nsmenuitem-not-updating-on-second-display)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSProgressIndicator like this, it also works with Lion:

```
@interface UnanimatedProgressIndicator : NSProgressIndicator {
@private
    BOOL    isAnimating;
}
@end

@interface NSProgressIndicator (HeartBeat)
- (void) heartBeat:(id)sender;      // Apple internal method for the animation
@end

@implementation UnanimatedProgressIndicator

- (void) startAnimation:(id)sender
{
    isAnimating = YES;
    [super startAnimation:sender];
}

- (void) stopAnimation:(id)sender
{
    isAnimating = NO;
    [super stopAnimation:sender];
}

- (void) heartBeat:(id)sender
{
    if (isAnimating)
        [super heartBeat:sender];
}

@end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - I've tried using this verbatim, but heartBeat: doesn't appear to ever be called.

Comment: I love when Apple creates complexity on a thing that is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using the same approach as described previously, with one small change.

When the menu's delegate receives `menuNeedsUpdate:`, I send `setAnimationDelay:` (with the sufficiently huge number as the arg) to each progress bar.  This is working reliably now, so I'm happy enough with it.

Comment: This method **setAnimationDelay:** is deprecated in 10.5 and does not seem to work at all on Lion. I am not sure how this can be done now.

Comment: It works without complaint when using bindings to set the delay.  I don't have Lion though, so I have no idea if that will work there.